# TypeScript generic function, unexpected behavior when generic is a class

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class Class {
}
const f0 = <T extends typeof Class> (c:T): T => {
  return c
}
const call0 = f0 (Class) //ok

const f1 = <T extends typeof Class> (c:T): T => {
  const a = new c()
  return a //TS2322: Type 'Class' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Class'.
}
const call1 = f1 (Class)

const f2 = <T extends typeof Class> (c:T):InstanceType<T> => {
  const a = new c()
  return a //TS2322: Type 'Class' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType '.
}
const call2 = f1 (Class)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5WgbwFAF8XAPYDsIBdoAzABmgF5oAeAFWgFMAPfenAExnwE8AHerInAQQAfNAAUwAFw0AlFOh1yY1NGgAnevgCu6nNGDpMuAgbAgQZSqQnxIEWdAD0TrAGsUxvISIBGCtR0TCzsnLz8gnZQYpIy8ooUKihq2N7QYAE49ADuBuKyyRpauvoZLjQAygBMAMxVVQo04dAA5FEQLdAAljA4WIT2XQDmOGAARiD00PhY080tNC0AdGqtiwZY2iBs0GNTXd5gOPhdYCw72V34ABbppepjV+pg6lxzfNDZ113At9hbOz20G0OE04HO01mbWEyyMqVMwHMIH81n84naBS8piIVQCtAYzFYHHeESE9hi0jkUgAkoccMB6E0+LQxMpkIV4QNMjk8gU1JodHp0s4nJVavVGvN2p0etA+gMoMNRhMpjMSa1aQQjgymVNYRhOWYLLjUbZhLIgA)

The argument is typed as T, so why isn't that acceptable for the return type?

Comment: @pilchard The answer is hidden in there but it's very hard to understand it if you don't already know it. This question is using `typeof Class` to get a constructor which the question you mentioned is doesn't mention. Using `typeof Class` instead of a generic constructor type is what caused the problem

Comment: To those who closed this question. The accepted answer on the linked question is to use `InstanceType<T>` which the OP was already using. The linked answer does not answer the problem posted here which was how to create a generic constructor type. The solution to the OP's problem does not involve using `InstanceType`. Please don't close a question linking to another question whose accepted answer does not address this post's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first snippet doesn't make a lot of sense. It says that it takes something that is a constructor that returns a `Class` instance. That `T` extends `new () => Class`;

It also says it returns the same T (a constructor), but you are returning an instance; that doesn't make sense.

### Solution

You were a lot closer in your second snippet

```
const f2 = <T extends typeof Class> (c:T): InstanceType<T> => {
  const a = new c()
  return a //TS2322: Type 'Class' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType '.
}
```

Again, `typeof Class` expands to `{new() => Class}` but what you really want is a generic constructor, so you can't just use `typeof Class`, you have to write your own type for the generic constructor of `Class`. Then your return type is a lot simpler.

```
class Class {  a = 1; }

class SubClass extends Class {  b = 2; }

class OtherClass {  c = 3; }

type ClassCtor<T extends Class> = new () => T;

const f = <C extends Class> (c: new() => C): C => {
  return new c();
}

// OR
const f = <C extends Class> (c: ClassCtor<C>): C => {
  return new c();
}



// It's a Class instance
const call1 = f(Class);

// It's a SubClass instance
const call2 = f(SubClass);

// Fails compilation
const call3 = f(OtherClass);
```

See [live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5Wgb2tM0C80CMBuaAvgFBGiQwDKArgEbznQCmAHgC6MB2AJjPYitBqZoAJnzFSCGAHlWAC0YAnPjAHBhAZnElWATwAOjOFNisA9ooA8AFSZtOPY+QB8wjowDu0ABQBKTK7WuCTAZhwQrNAAZsKWsHbs3LxSrt7AAFzQ7h5+AXC+mfEYrkhEqIqMrFSKHFme0MB+wRKh4ZFRIrHxLImOKqkZTlCmFnHOBXB5peWV1bXZDU1EEgD0K9AAkqwA5DDoKtAAlm1gHMCMpGERDWAgINjCUd4qvsFEa5s7e9DUdFJHJzOF1a12AtxAnSwT1+LzeHwAYmBDiAYKEALb6ZFgViHMKXNo3O4aR7eWQKZRSV4kEgfLa7NBDGDHCKnc740Hg7APKEiZ6UuHrOnfGH-ZmsVnAq6RMF3ESQ6K8kXkKnvdaI5GoswYrE4vEg6XgjTEnmk+RKWFEIA)

Comment: Did you mean `const f = <C extends Class> (c: ClassCtor<C>): C => {...`? (you never use your constructor type). Nice explanation though.

Comment: I just inlined the constructor type... But yes, that's how it would be used.

Comment: I saw that, just thought it might clarify the concept to make use of the custom type.